# Configure virtual serial port between 2 vmware fusion virtual machine

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, vmware-fusion, virtual-serial-port

I'm developing a program that sends a file from one computer to another between a RS232 serial port.

I can test it on the school computers just fine, but I would like to be able to test it at home. So I'm trying to connect 2 virtual machines between a virtual serial port in vmware fusion, but I don't understand how to configure it.

I've installed the 2 virtual machines and added a serial port to each one (in the settings). But the only available option is to name the file that the serial port will use. This name will be used how?

I'm working with the /dev/ttyS1 port, can I still use it normally, and somehow redirect the output to the file that was configured?

Comment: So, it was easy. You have to use the same file in each virtual machine. When you try to save the same file on the second vm it warns you that the file already exists, just say you want to replace it. 
Go into the share settings of each virtual machine and add the folder where the file is stored on your computer, and give it read and write permissions. In my case is the same folder where I keep the vm files.
Now I just have to open the file and exchange info between the 2 vm's. I had to comment a few things in my code (it's not a real serial port)but at least I can simulate it well enough.

Comment: You should make your comment an answer (and later accept it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it was easy. You have to use the same file in each virtual machine. When you try to save the same file on the second vm it warns you that the file already exists, just say you want to replace it. Go into the share settings of each virtual machine and add the folder where the file is stored on your computer, and give it read and write permissions. In my case is the same folder where I keep the vm files. Now I just have to open the file and exchange info between the 2 vm's. I had to comment a few things in my code (it's not a real serial port)but at least I can simulate it well enough.

Comment: Hi, I tried your system but I am unable to get it working. I would appreciate if you can confirm and give some more detailed instructions. I also would like to use two VM in Fusion to debug some apps that needs serial communication. Your idea is brilliant.